# How to test pipe with ChangeDetectorRef as a dependency and TestBed.inject?

Tags: angular, angular-test

I can test pipes with dependencies by instantiating them with TestBed.inject like well behaved Angular components, but if I try to do the same with a pipe that depends on ChangeDetectorRef I get an error. Why is that? Is there some Angular magic that forces devs to instantiate them with `new`?

Pipe:

```
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform,
} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'test'
})
export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    public changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  transform(text: string): string {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Test:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TestPipe } from './test.pipe';

describe('TestPipe', () => {
  let pipe: TestPipe;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TestPipe,
        { provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: {} }
      ],
    });
    pipe = TestBed.inject(TestPipe);
  });

  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
at createViewRef (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22871:1)
at injectChangeDetectorRef (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22851:1)
at ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:26593:1)
at Object.SanitizePipe_Factory [as factory] (ng:///SanitizePipe/ɵfac.js:4:40)
at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11353:1)
at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11174:1)
at NgModuleRef$1.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25254:1)
at TestBedRender3.inject (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:1686:1)
at Function.inject (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:1611:1)
at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/test.pipe.spec.ts:23:20)
```

Repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-noyce-y89uv

Comment: Why do you need this part: `{ provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useValue: {} }`?

Comment: It's a dependency (pipe's constructor), but I get the same error if I don't add that part.